# Does adding random numbers make them more random?

Tags: random

This is a purely theoretical question.

We all know that most, if not all, random-number generators actually only generate *pseudo-random* numbers.

Let's say I want a random number from 10 to 20. I can do this as follows (`myRandomNumber` being an integer-type variable):

```
myRandomNumber = rand(10, 20);
```

However, if I execute this statement:

```
myRandomNumber = rand(5, 10) + rand(5, 10);
```

Is this method *more* random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The randomness is not cumulative. The `rand()` function uses a uniform distribution  between your two defined endpoints.

Adding two uniformly distributions invalidates the uniform distribution. It will make a strange looking pyramid, with the most probability tending toward the center. This is because of accumulation of the probability density function with increasing degrees of freedom.

I urge you to read this:

[Uniform Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29)

and this:

[Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

Pay special attention to what happens with the two uniform distributions on the top right of the screen.

You can prove this to yourself by writing to a file all the sums and then plotting in excel. Make sure you give yourself a large enough sample size. 25000 should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand this is by considering the popular fair ground game "Lucky Seven".
If we roll a six sided die, we know that the probability of obtaining any of the six numbers is the same - 1/6.
What if we roll two dice and add the numbers that appear on the two ?
The sum can range from 2 ( both dice show 'one') uptil 12 (both dice show 'six')
The probabilities of obtaining different numbers from 2 to 12 are no longer uniform. The probability of obtaining a 'seven' is the highest. There can be a 1+6, a 6+1, a 2+5, a 5+2, a 3+4 and a 4+3. Six ways of obtaining a 'seven' out of 36 possibilities.
If we plot the distribution we get a pyramid. The probabilities would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1 (of course each of these has to be divided by 36).
The pyramidal figure (and the probability distribution) of the sum can be obtained by 'convolution.
If we know the 'expected value' and standard deviation ('sigma') for the two random numbers, we can perform a quick a ready calculation of the expected value of the sum of the two random numbers.
The expected value is simply the addition of the two individual expected values.
The sigma is obtained by applying the "pythagoras theorem" on the two individual sigmas (square root of the sum of the square of each sigma).