# Getting a random number in range larger than RAND_MAX (C)

Tags: c, random

I know RAND_MAX = 32767, though I need to get a random number in the range [0, 100000000].
Is there a way of getting that using rand() ?

thanks 
(Using C)

Comment: Call it twice or more, and add the results together.

Comment: @GoBusto  That's a bad move.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741158/does-adding-random-numbers-make-them-more-random

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920860/how-to-generate-large-random-numbers-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527108/generating-a-random-number-within-range-0-to-n-where-n-can-be-rand-max?rq=1

Comment: Adding multiple random numbers is not only slow but also incorrect. It requires n calls to random to generate a (m+n) bit number from an m-bit number. Instead, generate separate bits and or/xor them together

Answer (score 0):

According to [ISO C Random Number Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html) the value of RAND_MAX seems to be implementation dependent:

> The value of this macro is an integer constant representing the
>   largest value the rand function can return. In the GNU C Library, it
>   is 2147483647, which is the largest signed integer representable in 32
>   bits. In other libraries, it may be as low as 32767.

So perhaps you can try an alternate C library to achieve what you want.

Comment: Using my own computer, printing RAND_MAX gets 32767. What other C library are you talking about ?

Comment: @diora12 That result is going to depend on the C library that gets linked in by default to your program, which will depend on your compiler and/or linker.  You do not have to accept those defaults, but changing them is a different question all together.  BTW what compiler/linker are you using?